# Solo Scenario: Whirlpool Eddy

Tags: keyforge

Card says: "Action: Stun and exhaust 1 of your creatures that is not already stunned. If all of your creatures are stunned, destroy Whirlpool Eddy and lower the tide. "

What to do, if I have no creature in the battleline?

Destroy eddy, or only exhaust the artifact, and make it ready for the turn of the keyraken?

Answer (score 1):

If you have no creatures, then "all of your creatures are stunned" is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), thus the second sentence applies.

Comment: How can all of my creatures be stunned if I dont have any?

Comment: @Anon99,  Because you don't have any creatures that aren't stunned. As the link says,  "[it's] true because the antecedent cannot be satisfied".